# (MASM32) How would I create a macro to obtain a string from user input?

Tags: macros, scanf, masm32

I am still pretty new to Assembly and currently taking an introductory class at my local community college.

One of the requirements for our assignments was to use macros to print text and take in user input.

I am pretty sure my printing code is right:

```
displayString MACRO message:REQ
  lea  eax, message
  push eax
  call printf    
  add esp, 4
ENDM
```

I am confused though on how I would go about getting the user input. Here is what I have so far:

```
obtainString MACRO input:REQ, msgformat:REQ
  lea eax, input
  push eax
  lea eax, msgformat
  push eax
  call scanf
  add esp, 8
ENDM
```

Because the macro is a separate file, I am pretty sure the variables do not transfer to my main file. I am just wondering how would I transfer the contents of 'input' from the macros file to a variable in my main file.
Thank you.

Side note: For some reason my project will not compile because it cannot find the macros file although it is in the same folder as the main file.

Answer (score 0):

`input` is not a variable, it's a macro parameter. Macros are essentially just a text replacement feature. So when you write something like:

```
obtainString foo, bar
```

the assembler will replace that line with:

```
lea eax, foo
push eax
lea eax, bar
push eax
call scanf
add esp, 8
```

So there's nothing to "transfer". Whatever label you pass as the first argument to `obtainString` is where the user input will be written to.